# bash script do not save output file although required

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Wrote the following simple .sh script which should save output.txt to the working directory:

```
valuesfile="values.*"

for f in ./
do
 if [[ $f = $valuesfile ]]
 then
     yq d $f 'resources.' >./output.txt
 fi
done
```

When I execute the script, no file is created. all folders have rwx permissions including the script itself.

Comment: Check what the script outputs without the redirection to file. I'm not familiar with `yq` but the `d` looks strange. Usually one would expect an option to be proceeded by at least 1 `-`

Comment: Looks like the body of the `if` will never execute.

Comment: Yes. That's odd as well!

Comment: You should refresh yourself on how shell filename expansion works.

Comment: On the plus side, at least you're not making the common beginner mistake of trying to use `ls` here.

Answer (score 0):

Just read this piece of code:

```
valuesfile="values.*"
...
 if [[ $f = $valuesfile ]]
```

I don't think that any file can be called `values.*`, I'm expecting something like `values.1` or `values.txt`, but a filename containing an asterisk look weird to me.

**Edit after comment**

I propose the following:

```
valuesfile="values.*"

for f in ./$valuesfile
do
     yq d $f 'resources.' >./output.txt
done
```

Comment: by values.* I meant to regex. Inside the working dir I want to take all the files which start with "values" and do the yq command on each one of them.

Comment: Why do you even use regex? I believe something like `for f in ./$valuefile` should do the trick, isn't it? No need for the `if`-clause.

Comment: I've updated my answer (without testing, however), do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I understand, but valuesfile is not a repo so how can you do "for f in ./$valuesfile"? Sorry if I have lack of knowledge..

Comment: I want to go over all the files inside the directory: /usr/src/mydir/. Inside /mydir there are some files which their name starts with "values"... So I want to go over these files only and do the yq command.

Comment: You can simply do `for f in /usr/src/mydir/values.*`, this means "take all the files, located inside that particular directory and having a filename, starting with "values."", you're combining both location and filename similarity into one statement.

Comment: It looks like "in /usr/src/mydir/values.*" is looking for directory, while I give it a filename "values.*"

Comment: "Error: open /usr/src/mydir/values.*: no such file or directory". (And yes there are two values files)

Answer (score 0):

Your condition can never be true, and therefore, `yq` is never executed.

The loop body is executed exactly once, with `f` set to the string `./`, and `valuesfile` is set to the string `values.*`. These strings are obviously not equal.

Comment: by values.* I meant to regex. Inside the working dir I want to take all the files which start with "values" and do the yq command on each one of them.

Comment: You don't do a regex match in your script. This would be done by the `=~` operator, not by `=`. For finding  files where the name starts with _values_, a regexp is overkill. Wildcard pattern match is sufficient. You could much a filename stored in variable `filename` simply by `[[ $filename == values* ]]`. Of course even this would not fix your problem, because of the non-sense value stored in your variable `f`....

Comment: please take a loon on my new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67089998/sh-script-doesnt-work-as-expected-on-docker-container

Answer (score 0):

Your glob is never expanded: unquoted parameter expansions inside `[[ ... ]]` do not undergo pathname expansions. Your loop is also incorrect: `for f in ./` iterates exactly once, setting `f` to the string `./`, rather than iteration over the files in the current directly. And finally, if there *are* more than one matching file, you'll repeatedly overwrite the previous contents of `output.txt`; use `>>` instead.

You *could* try

```
valuesfile="values.*"

for f in ./$valuesfile
do
     yq d "$f" 'resources.' >> ./output.txt
done
```

though this will cause problems if any of your files have whitespace, as the expansion of `$valuesfile` undergoes word-splitting as well as pathname expansion.

Use an array instead:

```
valuesfile=( values.* )

for f in "${valuesfile[@]}"
do
  yq d "$f" 'resources.' >> output.txt
done
```

Or, just dispense with the extra variable and put the pattern in the loop directly:

```
for f in values.*
do
  yq d "$f" 'resources.' >> output.txt
done
```

Comment: please take a loon on my new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67089998/sh-script-doesnt-work-as-expected-on-docker-container